# Finding Duplicates via Query in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

In my table I have a number of products. It's come to my attention that someone has uploaded some products using the same code. How can I run a query that will find all rows that are NOT unique in the productno field?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: didn't know where to start, so no

Comment: Scotch's answer should work well to identify the rows, once you have removed/fixed duplicates you could consider setting the column's index setting to `Yes, no duplicates`, this will not allow any further duplicate products to be inserted but may give ugly errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand the question, you want to see which rows include duplicate `productno` values, not just which `productno` values are duplicated.

If that's correct, select the duplicate `productno` values in a subquery and join your table to the subquery.

```
SELECT y.*
FROM
    [Your Table] AS y
    INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT [productno], Count(*)
            FROM [Your Table]
            GROUP BY [productno]
            HAVING Count(*) > 1
        ) AS sub
    ON y.[productno] = sub.[productno]
ORDER BY y.[productno];
```

Comment: I think I'm either misunderstanding something, or I was misunderstood. When I run this Query, I get the popup to input a value. I came across a few producst that had the same values, so now out of fear that others (of our 3000+ products) may have been uploaded the same way. So I'm just hoping there's a show query that will show any rows that have a productno that is not unique.

Comment: My bad, when I typed it in, I accidentally had a spelling mistake on productno. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 SELECT productno, count(*) as num FROM Products GROUP BY ProductNo HAVING count(*)  > 1
```